# Opening Excel file located in one drive

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I need to open the excel file located in share point using Excel.Application

In Visual Basic 6, I am using following to open the excel file located in Sharepoint:

```
Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE https://livecnm-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/sghimire_cnm_edu/EZwyv4Ot1_xEnIeT1SIADncBVtRQ0b6THoJj0eLrbpEjXQ?e=NgyEBD", vbNormalFocus
```

But i want to use Excel.Application instead of shell so, i can hide ribbon, status bar, formula bar and other stuff before excel file open.I have tried following but it not working:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlApp
.Workbooks.Open "https://livecnm-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/sghimire_cnm_edu/EZwyv4Ot1_xEnIeT1SIADncBVtRQ0b6THoJj0eLrbpEjXQ?e=NgyEBD"
.Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
.Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
.Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
.Application.DisplayScrollBars = True
.Application.Visible = True

End With
```

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code.  Have you tried setting `xlApp.Visible = True` so you can see what's going on?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your comment, i tried it and isnot opening the right file, it opeining a new excel file with this "EZwyv4Ot1_xEnIeT1SIADncBVtRQ0b6THoJj0eLrbpEjXQ" as file name and same text as name of sheet.

I have verified the file location and the link is correct, when i do shell function as i mentioned above it opens right file.

Comment: How did you verfify the link? Did you do it with `ThisWorkbook.FullName`?

Comment: @Storax I can open the file when i do 
Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE https://livecnm-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/sghimire_cnm_edu/EZwyv4Ot1_xEnIeT1SIADncBVtRQ0b6THoJj0eLrbpEjXQ?e=NgyEBD", vbNormalFocus

Comment: Sorry but it would be nice if you wouldn't mind answering my question?

Comment: @Storax I  am sorry if missunderstood your question, i got that link from manage access > Anyone with link can view and copied the link. How do i get a link like yours which point directly to the excel file likes yours with file type

Comment: See my comment above. Did you try the code from my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you give this a try

```
Sub open_excel_from_one_drive()
    Dim sfilename As String
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim xlsheet As Workbook

    sfilename = "https://d.docs.live.net/78a58439bd7a4267/Investment%20Spreadsheet/Customer%20Management/Security%20Data.xlsm"
    Set xl = Application
    Set xlsheet = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename)

End Sub
```

If you want to go on using your code then you could try

```
Sub dummy_Code()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With xlApp
        .Workbooks.Open "https://d.docs.live.net/78a58439bd7a4267/Investment%20Spreadsheet/Customer%20Management/Security%20Data.xlsm"
        .Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
        .Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
        .Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
        .Application.DisplayScrollBars = True
        .Application.Visible = True

    End With
End Sub
```